# Максимальное и минимальное число в массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Вводим число и сразу толкаем в массив. После этого ищем максимальное и минимальное число. На экран максимальное выводится корректно, а минимальное всегда 0. Как быть, элементарная задача, но сижу и туплю, ничего понять не могу.

```
public class Task2 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите количество чисел: ");

        int a = s.nextInt();

        int[] mas = new int[a];
        int max = mas[0], min = mas[0];

        System.out.println("Введите числа в массив: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            mas[i] = s.nextInt();
        }           

        for(int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            if(mas[i] > max) 
                max = mas[i];

            if(mas[i] < min) 
                min = mas[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальное число: " + max);
        System.out.println("Минимальное число: " + min);            
    }    
}
```

Comment: вы `max` и `min` присваиваете до заполнения массива, поэтому в них изначально всегда 0.

Comment: в общем поменяйте местами чтение и объявление max/min.

Comment: @zRrr Спасибо, присвоил после заполнение) Чем больше стараешься учить джаву, тем больше тупишь в элементарных вещах :(

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```