# Как найти минимальное и максимальное значение массива Java

Tags: java, массивы

При решении задания столкнулся с задачей, немогу разобраться как правильно:

- найти минимальное и максимальное значение  массива

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Объявляем Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter array length from 1 to 100: ");

        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int arrLength = input.nextInt();

            if (arrLength > 100) {
                System.out.println("Enter array length from 1 to 100: ");
            } else {
                // заполнить числами случайным образом (в диапазоне [-50.00; 50.00])
                double[] arr = new double[100];

                Random random = new Random();

                double a = -50.00;
                double b = 50.00;

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i] = a + random.nextDouble() * (b - a);
                    System.out.printf("%.2f ", arr[i]);
                }

                // найти минимальный элемент массива

                // найти максимальный элемент массива
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: да, сумма элементов массива / кол-во элементов

Comment: да, думаю справлюсь :)

Comment: С максимумом и минимумом справитесь? Или есть сомнения?

Comment: нет, с минимальным и максимальным зашел в тупик. Код похожий находил, но никак немогу решить таску, нужна помошь

Comment: Впишите код вашей попытки для максимума в вопрос. Там, наверняка, мелочь какая-нибудь.

Comment: Какая помощь? Тут пока что нечему помогать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Максимальное и минимальное число в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587177/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: Решил задание, подсмотрел аналогичное решение [максимальное и минимальное значение массива](https://irenoo.com/question/how-to-find-min-and-max-value-of-java-array/).

Исправил исходный код.

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего в такой задаче все таки спрашивают не умение пользоваться готовыми решениями джавы и библиотек, а умение строить алгоритмы самому. Лучшим алгоритмом в таком случае будет завести отдельные переменные max и min (оба типа double, min должен быть изначально присвоен как максимально возможное значение, а max - как минимально возможное в условиях Вашей задачи. (50.00 и -50.00 соответсвенно) и пройтись по всему массиву, на каждом из элементов вызывая проверку: если элемент меньше чем текущий минимальный, то присвоить минимальному значение элемента, а если больше текущего максимального, то присвоить максимальному значение текущего элемента массива. Если вам позволяет условие, то можете проводить проверку еще в процессе генерации массива, это будет наиболее оптимально. Я думаю, в код Вы это легко переведете. Удачи!

Comment: В идеале переменные max и min заполнять нужно первым существующим элементом массива. 1. это в последствии избавит от глюков в ЯП с нестрогой типизацией. 2. на два сравнения меньше (что может дать существенный прирост производительности, если когда-то придется искать мах и мин в огромном кол-ве массивов из 2-3-х элементов). 3. не введет начинающего в ступор при решении аналогичной задачи, но без явного указания диапазона значений. Мелочь конечно, но некоторые могут зациклиться на этих границах диапазона и прощай карьера программиста. )))

Answer (score 0):

можно написать цикл, реализацию которого, ты найдёшь на первых страницах поиска, если введёшь свой запрос в гугл.
или так.

```
        //сортируем массив
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        //выводим 1й и последний элемент массива
        System.out.println("min: " + arr[0] +  " max: " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Это специальный анти-паттерн популярный у начинающих. Так не надо делать, непрофессионально.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy а можно в 2х словах что плохого в этом решении?

Comment: Меняется исходный массив, сложность `NlogN`. Можно и сохранить массив и решить задачу за линейное время: `Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsDouble()`.

Comment: Ещё так: `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr))`. В обоих случаях даже дополнительная память не нужна. Все дополнительные структуры просто ссылки на исходный массив.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что дошел к такому решению:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            myArray[i] = a + random.nextDouble() * (b - a);
            System.out.printf("%.2f   ", myArray[i]);
        }
        double max = a - 1;
        for(int k = 0; k  max){
                max = myArray[k];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nMax value: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f ", max);

        double min = b + 1;
        for(int c = 0; c < size; c++){
            if(myArray[c] < min){
                min = myArray[c];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nMin value: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f ", min);

        double totalAvarage = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            summ = totalAvarage + myArray[j];
        }
        double avg = (totalAvarage / size);

        System.out.println("\nAverage value: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f ", avg);
    }
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не нужно повторять вычисление максимума, минимума и среднего в цикле. Сперва заполните массив, затем вычислите нужные характеристики.

Comment: Вычислять максимум и минимум вам нужно без использования `Collections`. Это учебное задание. Его цель научить вас писать циклы.